# Couldn't connect to Docker daemon at http+docker://localhost with docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-container

I have this React app that I want to run on an Apache HTTP Docker container.

So I created a **Dockerfile** that works with `sudo docker build` and `sudo docker run <name>`

```
FROM httpd:2.4
COPY ./dist/ /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/
```

I created a **docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
  frontend:
    build: .
    ports:
     - "8080:80"
    container_name: frontend
```

But when I run `sudo docker-compose build` I get this error:

> ERROR: Couldn't connect to Docker daemon at http+docker://localhost -
>   is it running?
>
> If it's at a non-standard location, specify the URL with the
>   DOCKER_HOST environment variable.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 61):

Check your privileges, Following command solved my problem :

```
sudo chown $USER /var/run/docker.sock
```

It happens when you try to start docker as non super user and it couldn't get access to it own sockets.

Comment: Almost 3 years later, worked like a charm.

Answer (score 19):

run with sudo:

**sudo** docker-compose up -d

Comment: Instead of using `sudo` follow: https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/linux-postinstall/

Comment: Following the link mentioned by itsazzad, don't forget to logout and login again to recognize the new group membership.

Answer (score 7):

My solution was to simply restart the box (EC2 Amazon Linux2).
Chased my tail for 30 mins with permissions and groups, but a simple reboot did the trick.

Comment: Thank you for your sugestion. I was also chasing my tails for hours, and after rebooting the server it started to work.
Why any tutorial or readme file don't say to restart?

Comment: Thank god I saw your answer. I spent the last 2 hours trying to figure out what was wrong. Just needed to restart as well. Thanks a tonne.

Answer (score 7):

I had this, and discovered that my user was not in the `docker` group, and so didn't have permission.

You can check this by running `groups`. If `docker` isn't in the list that's printed, this may be your problem.

You can add your user to the `docker` group with:

```
sudo usermod -aG docker yourUserName
```

After adding my user to the docker group, I had to log out and back in again for the changes to take effect.

EDIT: I did this on a fresh install, and discovered that I needed to reboot before it worked. If you're not sure why it failed, try rebooting!

Comment: Thank you for suggesting that people *actually fix* their permissions rather than just run everything at root!  Linux groups are loaded at login, so you don't need a full reboot. Just logout and login again.

Answer (score 6):

Before running any Docker command, you need to run the Docker daemon on the host machine:

```
sudo systemctl start docker
```

Comment: it is running. I can run any Docker command, like `ps`, `build` etc. And i can run docker-compose in another project right now. But when I run only docker-compose in this HTTPD project, I get this error.

Comment: I see. It is likely a permissions issue then. See [here](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4181)

Comment: same symptom in a Jenkins environment. docker commands work, but docker-compose failes with the message in the subject. As user jenkins from the CLI I can do all docker commands (via /var/run/docker.sock), but calling docker-compose from the Jenkins job will cause the problem.

Comment: @rhoerbe how did you fix your issue with the Jenkinsfile?

Comment: On Debian 11 works.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same error, but in my case it was an invalid docker-compose file: image name was `my_app:`. E.g

```
  my_app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./my_app/Dockerfile
    image: my_app:
```

The error is very unhelpful and took me a long time to figure out, as it was not explicitly written like that in the file, but instead the part after `:` was an empty variable.

Leaving this here in case someone else stumbles on this issue.

Answer (score 1):

for me helped

```
export DOCKER_HOST=127.0.0.1:2375
```